# invalid JSON in message

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs, rethinkdb

this is my code ----

```
var nsq = require('nsqjs');
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var nsqvar = (process.env.NSQD_RETH || "localhost:4161").split(",");
    var p = r.connect({host:'localhost', port:8080, db:'test', authKey:''});{
        p.then(function(conn) {
            console.log("Succesfull connection")
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log("Error at  connection")
        })
        // Event Reader functionality inside connect callback
        var eventreader;
        eventreader = new nsq.Reader('hello_topic', 'hello_channel', {
            lookupdHTTPAddresses: nsqvar
        });
        eventreader.connect();
        eventreader.on('message', function (msg) {
            // Now we have access to the connection
            r.table('sprinkle_nsq_test').insert(msg.json()).run(conn);
            console.log('Received message [%s]: %s', msg.id, msg.body.toString());
            msg.finish();
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
```

And from the terminal I am trying to insert

`curl -d '{"id": "712", "name": "Douglas Adams""type "casdasdasomedy"}' 'http://127.0.0.1:4151/put?topic= hello_topic'`

At nsq at receives the message but at nodejs program at says  **throw new Error("Invalid JSON in Message");
              ^
Error: Invalid JSON in Message**

and also at same time the message is not storing at rethinkdb.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: What is the output of `msg.json()`? Can you console.log it and post it?

Comment: Also, your `insert` statement doesn't have access to your `conn` variable. They are in different scopes. Basically, your `conn` variable is `undefined` when you pass it to `run`. So your query won't execute.

Comment: Also, if you're running RethinkDB with its default settings, you have to connect to port 28015 not 8080. 8080 is the web admin port and the 28015 is the client driver port.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error message is correct - your `JSON` is invalid.

Try copying and pasting it through an online [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) / [viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) and it will be invalid.

I've cleaned it up below. Hope it all works now.

```
{"id": "712", "name": "Douglas Adams", "type": "casdasdasomedy"}
```

Comment: it still show the same error ----   throw new Error("Invalid JSON in Message");
              ^
Error: Invalid JSON in Message

Comment: @Christofer Please post your new `curl` line the please, so I can see what you're sending

Comment: curl -d '{"id": "712", "name": "Douglas Adams", "type "comedy"}' 'http://127.0.0.1:4151/put?topic=hello_topic'

Comment: That's still invalid! You haven't used the example I gave you, nor have you tested your JSON in either of the links I provided. This `"type "comedy"` , needs to be  `"type": "comedy"`

Comment: i think i am actually doing something wrong at rethinkdb, cause when i try to see the connection at rethinkdb it show "error at connection", can you kindly look where i am mistaking at my node.js application

Comment: Sorry - not a JS developer, so I can't comment on that. All I can see is invalid JSON, and an error message saying "invalid JSON". I'd make sure the source JSON was fixed before you move onto something else.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your code (in regards to RethinkDB at least). Here is a fixed solution with comments (this may or may not fix your problem):

```
var nsq = require('nsqjs');
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var nsqvar = (process.env.NSQD_RETH || "localhost:4161").split(",");
// Connect to the client driver port 28015
var p = r.connect({ host:'localhost', port:28015, db:'test' });

p.then(function(conn) {
    // Wait until the database is connected
    console.log("Succesfull connection");

    // Event Reader functionality inside connect callback
    var eventreader;
    eventreader = new nsq.Reader('hello_topic', 'hello_channel', {
        lookupdHTTPAddresses: nsqvar
    });
    eventreader.connect();
    eventreader.on('message', function (msg) {
        // Make sure msg.json() is actually valid json
        if (typeof msg === 'object' && msg !== null) {
          throw new TypeError('`msg` is already and object. It doesnt need to be convert to json');
        }
        var json = msg.json();
        if (typeof json !== 'object' && msg !== null) {
          throw new TypeError('`msg.json()` is not an object and cant be inserted into the database.');
        }
        // Now we have access to the connection
        r.table('sprinkle_nsq_test').insert(msg.json()).run(conn)
          .then(function () {
            // Wait until RethinkDB is done inserted the message to call `.finish`
            console.log('Received message [%s]: %s', msg.id, msg.body.toString());
            msg.finish();
            console.log(msg);
          });
    });
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log("Error at connection to the database");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jorge, but somehow it shows   ---  console.log("Error at connection to the database");    i can't find out the problem

Comment: I guess you should make sure the RethinkDB instances is running and is listening in the specificed ports. What happens when you go to localhost:8080? Do you get the admin UI? What happens when you run `rethinkdb` in your terminal?

Comment: when i goto localhost:8080 i have the access of rethinkdb and when i write rethinkdb at terminal it shows ------

Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
error: Could not bind to http port: The address at localhost:8080 is reserved or already in use.

Comment: It seems that RethinkDB is running somewhere and the http port is bound to 8080 but the intracluster port and the client driver port are not set to their defaults. A quick fix to this might be running `rethinkdb -o 1` to offset all ports by one and then try connecting through port 28016. http://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/

Comment: Christofer: What is the content of `error` when the connection fails? Maybe we will find some useful hints in the error message.

Comment: Also please double-check that you're connecting to port 28015, not 8080. Port 8080 is the web console, not the port for connecting RethinkDB clients.